# Autodesk Viewer setZoomOutLimitFactor(factor) does not work

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I would like to ask if anyone else had problems trying to limit the maximum Zoom value of the **Autodesk** viewer using the **setZoomOutLimitFactor** command

I would like to fully control the *Zoom out* max and *Zoom in* max function.

I used it this way until a few months ago

```
window.Viewer.navigation.setZoomOutLimitFactor (
     window.Viewer.navigation.getZoomOutLimitFactor () / 2,
);
```

Trying to execute the command through the Console in the browser also does not obtain more success with that same command.

The documentation does not help much, it never had examples and it says nothing if it was overlooked.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Navigation/#setzoomoutlimitfactor-factor

Edited--
Tested on the last version of *modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.js*

Som new testes on 21 versions

**LMV_VIEWER_VERSION**

```
version     work
"7.20.1"    no
"7.19.0"    no
"7.18.0"    no
"7.17.1"    no
"7.16.1"    no
"7.15.3"    yes
"7.14.0"    yes
"7.13.1"    yes
"7.12.2"    yes
"7.11.0"    yes
"7.10.2"    yes
"7.9.0"     yes
"7.8.0"     yes
"7.7.0"     yes
"7.6.1"     yes
"7.5.1"     VNR
"7.4.2"     yes
"7.3.0"     yes
"7.2.1"     yes
"7.1.1"     yes
"7.0.4"     Yes
```

PS: Backlog page continues do not work.
VNR = Viewer Not Work

Comment: can confirm to be able to reproduce the issue - checking with our Engineering now

Comment: I'm tested on version "7.0.4" and still works!
I use the command  LMV_VIEWER_VERSION to verify
In my project in the latest version "7.20.1" it doesn't work, but it doesn't record anything about the operation.

I'm looking for Changelog to see any changes on the versions but "404 - The page you’re looking for doesn’t exist"
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/changelog/

Comment: Thanks for letting us know - I've passed this on to Engineering (`LMV-5508`) to look into this regression and will let you know soon.